# RxJava - different schedulers for each observable inside combineLatest

Tags: android, rx-java, combinelatest

I'm using `combineLatest` like in the example here -

```
Observables.combineLatest(
            observable1,
            observable2
        )
            .subscribeOn(schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(schedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeBy( ... )
```

And and I want to set different schedulers: `schedulers.computation()` for `observable1` and `schedulers.io()` `observable2`.

Is there a way to do it and how can I test it or print Logs to verify that it works as expected?

Comment: Apply `subscribeOn` onto them directly. Then apply `doOnNext` with logging after that. `observable1.subscribeOn(...).doOnNext(v -> log(v))`.

Comment: @akarnokd but how do I log info about which scheduler is being used? v represents a pair of values from what I understand

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().getName()`